# Read trigger event info in cloud build

Tags: google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have created a cloud build with Trigger event push to branch. I have added 2 files in included file filter. So when ever I updated those files my cloud build is triggering fine. But I want to know which file is updated, based on that I need to implement some other logic.

I can use $(body.commit) it printing all the commit information. but i need only files list which are modified in this commit.

Answer (score 1):

Here a code sample to know which Cloud Run directory has changed in my project

```
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
    id: "Init devops and list changes"
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - -c
      - |
          git fetch --depth=2
          # List the Cloud Run changes
          git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD^ HEAD -- cloud-run/ | sed 's/^[ 0-9.]\+% //g' | cut -d'/' -f2 | uniq > /workspace/change-in-cloudrun
```

I got the previous commit and compare what changed. I saved the result in a workspace file to be able to reuse the file later on.

Comment: Thanks for the info Deutsche guillaume blaquiere. just FYI I found another way as well. We can get the committed files from the variables. We need to use $(commit.files['*'].filename) as a value then we can retrieve files modified in the last commit.